# how to implement pause command(lavalink)?

Tags: discord.py

I'm trying to make a pause command. I'm using discord.py and lavalink and this is the error that I get: 'DefaultPlayer' object has no attribute 'pause'

This is the code that I'm using:

```
class MusicCog(commands.Cog):
  def __init__(self, bot):
    self.bot = bot
    self.bot.music = lavalink.Client(self.bot.user.id)
    self.bot.music.add_node('localhost', 7000, 'testing', 'na', 'music-node')
    self.bot.add_listener(self.bot.music.voice_update_handler, 'on_socket_response')
    self.bot.music.add_event_hook(self.track_hook)

  commands.command(name='pause')
  async def pause(self, ctx):
    player = self.bot.music.player_manager.get(ctx.guild.id)
    await player.pause()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`player.pause()` is from another object type.
You must use `player.set_pause(True)` in order to work. To unpause the playback you simply do `player.set_pause(False)`